# Обновление переменной без заморозки кода. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while

Недавно я столкнулся с такой проблемой как каждый кадр нужно было брать переменную. Я пытался делать это через цикл `while True`. Но проблема в том, что этот бесконечный цикл фризит скрипт. И из за этого переменные даже не могут отобразится в консоль. Так вот, как  обновлять переменные без фриза скрипта.

```py
while True:
    a = str(pyautogui.position()))
    print(a)
```

Comment: Может быть, tkinter?  Вот пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388625/update-a-variable-every-second-in-python

Comment: Чтобы отобразить переменную в консоль, нужно использовать например print. В показанном вами цикле никакого print нет, потому и не отображается.

Comment: Проблема не в том чтоб её написать, проблема в получении самой переменной

Comment: В коде, который вы показали (с исправлением опечаток), никакой заморозки нет, всё превосходно отображается в консоль и обновляется: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJVcF.gif

Comment: Проблема может быть в остальном коде.